# Understanding relative and absolute positioning: how to align an internal div to the bottom of the container

Tags: html, css, layout

still learning how to lay out with div and css. I have the following html:

```
<div id="Fascione">
</div>
<div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="Menu">
    </div>
    <div id="Contenuto">
        <div id="Liturgia">
        </div>
        <div id="Container">
            <div id="Ristorante">
            </div>
            <div id="Insieme">
            </div>
            <div id="Progetto">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Unitre">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Footer">
</div>
```

and css looks like:

```
html, body{width:100%;height:100%;}
body{width:1024px; margin:0px auto;padding:0px;border-width:0px;}
div#Fascione{width:inherit;height:125px;border-bottom:2px solid black;}
div#Wrapper{width:inherit;padding:8px 0px 8px 0px;/*background-color:#647;*/}
    div#Menu{float:left;width:200px;/*background-color:#F41;*/}
    div#Contenuto{margin-left:208px;/*background-color:#9bb;*/}
         div#Liturgia{float:left;width:34%;margin-bottom:1%;background-color:#987;}
         div#Container{float:left;width:65%;margin-bottom:1%;margin-left:1%;background-color:#aaaaaa;}
            div#Ristorante{float:left;width:49%;margin-bottom:1%;margin-left:1%;background-color:#123;}
            div#Insieme{float:left;width:49%;margin-bottom:1%;margin-left:1%;background-color:#abc;}
            div#Progetto{float:left;border-top:1px solid gray;background-color:#369;}
     div#Unitre{clear:left;border-top:1px solid gray;background-color:#de7;}
div#Footer{clear:left;width:inherit;height:40px;border-top:2px solid black;/*background-color:#1a9;*/} /* clear left needed! */
```

what I would like to do is to have the "Progetto" div bottom border stick together with the "Unitre" top border.

Reading other posts I tried to set the "Container" with position:relative and the "Progetto" with position:absolute;bottom:0px; but this does not do what I need.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I edited my css because I left over some "position relative" that indeed I was not using and I forgot to add some style that I defined for the body and html

Answer (score 0):

Setting containers with position relative is not a good practice.What you should try to do is zero out the margins beetween the two divs and only add border to the needed sides for example:

```
    Proggetto{
//no bottom border;
border:1px 1px 0 1px;
border-color:black;
margin:0;
}
Unitre{
border:1px solid black
margin:0;
}
```

Comment: I assume my mistakes in the css created a misunderstanding here. I tried your suggestion but it does not address my request.
I now edited my post hping that it is clearer.
Thanks anyway.